# Node.js Chat App host testing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have made a very simple chat application following this tutorial - [Tutorial Link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708). I have also made a website locally.

I have run my chat app through locally made server - http://127.0.0.1:3700/

But now I want to test it with a friend through another computer and see if we can chat to eachother. How is this done?  If I send him this server - http://127.0.0.1:3700/ , it doesn't work.

Do I need to host the app somewhere to test? Maybe github?

Comment: you can use ngrok to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using ngrok

[download ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download)

After downloading you have to expose your port

This is the sample in Mac OSX
[image]

Answer (score 0):

because you binding the address to **127.0.0.1** which is your machine local IP address.

When your friend putting **127.0.0.1:3700** it will point to his own machine instead of yours.

try to change the **127.0.0.1** to your own ip address, then ask your fiend to put **ipaddress:3700**.

how to get your IP address:

windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/15291/windows-find-pc-ip-address
Linux:http://www.wikihow.com/Check-the-IP-Address-in-Linux